# RHEL 6.9 - Upgrade OpenSSH from 5.3 to 7.3

Tags: rhel, openssh

We have **RHEL v6.9** server and **OpenSSH v5.3p1** is installed on it (confirmed by `rpm -q openssh` which outputs `openssh-5.3p1-123.el6_9.x86_64`). After the security testing, we are asked to upgrade **OpenSSH to v7.3**, to avoid any vulnerabilities.

I have tried `yum update openssh` and it says

```
No Packages marked for Update
```

Any idea, how can I update openssh? Is it even possible to update it to 7.3 on RHEL 6.9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re using the latest [officially packaged version of OpenSSH](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/openssh/5.3p1-123.el6_9/x86_64/fd431d51/package) on RHEL 6.9, which is still supported (and will be, without an extended support contract, until late 2020):

[image: OpenSSH package information from the RHEL customer portal, including the list of versions]

This means that all known vulnerabilities in your version of `openssh` are fixed, and newly-discovered vulnerabilities which are discovered in the future will be fixed — there’s no need to upgrade to the latest version of OpenSSH to avoid vulnerabilities.

That’s one of the points of using a supported distribution: you can rely on your distributor to take care of upstream vulnerabilities for you (as long as you keep your systems up-to-date).

To upgrade to [OpenSSH 7.4](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/openssh/7.4p1-13.el7_4/x86_64/fd431d51/package) you’d have to upgrade to RHEL 7, or build it yourself for RHEL 6 (and take on support for future vulnerabilities).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, however I can't access that [officially packaged version of OpenSSH](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/openssh/5.3p1-123.el6_9/x86_64/fd431d51/package) because I don't have a subscription there. Could you please share any screenshot of that page so I can use it as proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully *someone* in your organisation has access to that page, since you’re running RHEL... I’ve added a screenshot with the dropdown. There’s a message in the background stating that a more recent version is available, but that’s referring to the RHEL 7 versions.